# How to get CSS Footer to remain on show when main elements need placing above it

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I have been trying to create a Footer for my web page that will be anchored to the bottom of the page.
The problem I have is that so long as the 'main' content is set to "TOP:0;" the footer remains below the main content, no matter how much it expands.
But once I move the main data down a bit (e.g. "TOP:700px" in my example), the footer data disapears below the Main data.

I have tried using "position:absolute" and "position:relative", but no matter how I set this, unless all the main items are set to "TOP:0" the footer disapears.

Is there a way to make this work so that the footer stays below the main content, no matter where it is on the page?

(The reason is I have about 5 elements that need to be placed on the page at different points, but want to keep the footer showing)

```
<style>
body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

table
{
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    color:#000000;
}

#Container
{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#Header
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
}

#main
{
    padding:10px;
    padding-top:5px;    /* Height of the Header */
    padding-bottom:200px;   /* Height of the Footer */
}

#Footer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
}

#TabOne
{
    position:relative;
    top:700px;
}

#TabFt
{

}
</style>

<div id="container">    
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="main">

        <table id="TabOne">
            <th>TABLE ONE</th>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <Table id="TabFt">
            <th>!!FOOTER SHOULD BE BELOW TABLE ONE!!</th>
        </Table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could use jquery to set min-height of content = pageheigth - headerheight- footerheight

Comment: Do you want the footer to be at a fixed position on the browser client window?

Comment: Hi, it should be fixed to the bottom of the screen, below any content. So if there is a very small amount of content there will be a big gap between the content and the footer. If there is lots of content (scrolling off the bottom of the screen) the footer will be below all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
clear: both;
```

to the footer class?

This seemed to work for me when I was experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, but no joy I'm afraid. I added clear:both as suggested, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is an answer or just a 'fudge' but by changing "top:700px;" for the table to "padding-top:700px;" It appears to be doing what I want it to do.

I'm sure there is a reason why this is wrong, which I will no doubt find soon enough. but for now it seems to be working.